# DELETE SQL with two tables

Tags: mysql

This SELECT Query works well:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_lastvisit, n.user_id, n.multiple_counter, n.notification_id
FROM 
users u, notifications n
WHERE 
u.user_id = n.user_id
AND 
u.user_lastvisit < ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -1814400 )
```

I have to delete every entry in the notification table. I tried this:

```
DELETE notification_id FROM notifications
(SELECT u.user_id, u.user_lastvisit, n.user_id, n.multiple_counter, n.notification_id
FROM 
users u, notifications n
WHERE 
u.user_id = n.user_id
AND 
u.user_lastvisit < ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -1814400 ) )
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax of the `DELETE` statement is wrong. Use the following solution instead:

```
DELETE FROM notifications 
WHERE notification_id IN (
    SELECT x.notification_id
    FROM (
        SELECT notifications.notification_id
        FROM users, notifications
        WHERE users.user_id = notifications.user_id
    ) AS x
    WHERE x.user_lastvisit < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1814400)
);
```

You can use a `INNER JOIN` on `DELETE` for a smaller `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM notifications
    INNER JOIN users ON notifications.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE users.user_lastvisit < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1814400)
```

Comment: first gives You can't specify target table 'notifications' for update in FROM clause

Comment: you `UPDATE` or `DELETE`? You question was about `DELETE`!

Comment: DELETE but this was the error message - second solutions gives: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN users u ON n.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.user_lastvisit &lt;

Comment: tried first again, gives: You can't specify target table 'notifications' for update in FROM clause